# #include <comutil.h> cause errors

Tags: c++, clr

VS 2010 C++ CLR Library project, errors on adding comutil.h library

```
> Error 20  error LNK2001: unresolved
> external symbol "extern "C" long
> __stdcall VariantCopy(struct tagVARIANT *,struct tagVARIANT const
> *)" (?VariantCopy@@$$J18YGJPAUtagVARIANT@@PBU1@@Z)    D:\Projects\AL\Service\ncFlow\ncOPClient.NET\Stdafx.obj ncOPClient.NET
> Error 18  error LNK2001: unresolved
> external symbol "extern "C" void
> __stdcall VariantInit(struct tagVARIANT *)"
> (?VariantInit@@$$J14YGXPAUtagVARIANT@@@Z) D:\Projects\AL\Service\ncFlow\ncOPClient.NET\Stdafx.obj ncOPClient.NET
> Error 13  error LNK2001: unresolved
> external symbol "void __stdcall
> _com_issue_error(long)" (?_com_issue_error@@$$FYGXJ@Z)    D:\Projects\AL\Service\ncFlow\ncOPClient.NET\Stdafx.obj ncOPClient.NET
> Error 10  error LNK2028: unresolved
> token (0A000376) "void __stdcall
> _com_issue_error(long)" (?_com_issue_error@@$$FYGXJ@Z)
> referenced in function "void __cdecl
> _com_util::CheckError(long)" (?CheckError@_com_util@@$$FYAXJ@Z)   D:\Projects\AL\Service\ncFlow\ncOPClient.NET\Stdafx.obj ncOPClient.NET
> Error 4   error LNK2028: unresolved
> token (0A0003BC) "extern "C" void
> __stdcall VariantInit(struct tagVARIANT *)"
> (?VariantInit@@$$J14YGXPAUtagVARIANT@@@Z)
> referenced in function "public:
> __thiscall _variant_t::_variant_t(class _variant_t const &)" (??0_variant_t@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z)  D:\Projects\AL\Service\ncFlow\ncOPClient.NET\Stdafx.obj ncOPClient.NET
> Error 2   error LNK2028: unresolved
> token (0A0003D1) "extern "C" long
> __stdcall VariantCopy(struct tagVARIANT *,struct tagVARIANT const
> *)" (?VariantCopy@@$$J18YGJPAUtagVARIANT@@PBU1@@Z)
> referenced in function "public:
> __thiscall _variant_t::_variant_t(class _variant_t const &)" (??0_variant_t@@$$FQAE@ABV0@@Z)  D:\Projects\AL\Service\ncFlow\ncOPClient.NET\Stdafx.obj ncOPClient.NET
```

needed for

```
private:
        std::string from_variant(VARIANT& vt)
        {
            _bstr_t bs(vt);
            return std::string(static_cast<const char*>(bs));
        }
        /*
        void to_variant(const std::string& str, VARIANT& vt)
        {
            _bstr_t bs(str.c_str());
            reinterpret_cast<_variant_t&>(vt) = bs;
        }*/
```

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to MSDN, `_bstr_t` requires **comsuppw.lib**. Add this library to the linker dependencies list.

Comment: Wide char version?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: You don't need to fiddle with linker settings. `#include <comdef.h>` is enough; it will emit the correct linker settings by means of `#pragma comment(lib,...)`, based on whether or not `_DEBUG` is defined.

Comment: ... and whether or not *Treat WChar_t As Built in Type* is selected.

Answer (score 60):

try to include comdef.h,  don't include comutil.h

Comment: Excellent arcane knowledge. Works like a charm.

Comment: You just saved my life (I was using comip.h). Thank you!

Comment: Because `comdef.h` has pragmas like `# pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")` included. Which - on the other hand - `comutil.h` does not contain.

Answer (score 2):

Add the requisite import library as per the documentation, likely `Oleaut32.lib`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221236.aspx

**edit:**  I'm assuming the [Compiler COM Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) library subsumes this and Alex's answer would be the preferred library.

Comment: This is actually the right answer to which library needs to be included. +1