# Unresolved External Symbol with COM

Tags: c++, com, linker-errors, lnk2019

I'm writing a small class to interface with reading excel files through COM. So far all is ok, except when I attempt to read a cell's value.

During testing I was initially calling `getCell()` from the constructor just to check it was working and all was good. Once I started calling `getCell()` from outside the file I'm getting a LNK2019.

Here's a shortened sample:

*ExcelIO.h*

```
//MicroSoft Office Objects
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\mso.dll" \
rename("DocumentProperties", "DocumentPropertiesXL") \
rename("RGB", "RBGXL")

//Microsoft VBA Objects
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"

//Excel Application Objects
#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" \
rename("DialogBox", "DialogBoxXL") rename("RGB", "RBGXL") \
rename("DocumentProperties", "DocumentPropertiesXL") \
rename("ReplaceText", "ReplaceTextXL") \
rename("CopyFile", "CopyFileXL") \
exclude("IFont", "IPicture") no_dual_interfaces


class xlWorksheet {
public:
    xlWorksheet(Excel::_WorksheetPtr COMobjWs);

    template <class T>
    T getCell(int m, int n); // mth row, nth column
    template <>
    string getCell<string>(int m, int n);

private:
    Excel::_WorksheetPtr _COMobjWs {nullptr};
    Excel::RangePtr _usedRange {nullptr};
};


// TEMPLATE FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
template <class T>
T xlWorksheet::getCell(int m, int n) {
    T _temp;
    try {
        _temp = _usedRange->Item[m+1][n+1];
    }
    catch(...) {
        _temp = T {};
    }

    return _temp;
}


template <>
string xlWorksheet::getCell<string>(int m, int n) {
    // Get the _bstr_t value
    _bstr_t bstrt = getCell<_bstr_t>(m, n);

    // Detach the BSTR from the _bstr_t
    BSTR bstr = bstrt.Detach();

    // Initialize a blank string for the conversion (will be blank if conversion fails)
    string _temp;

    // Convert the BSTR into string
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        _temp.resize(len);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr, -1, &_temp[0], len, NULL, NULL);
    }

    delete bstr;
    return _temp;
}
```

There's nothing too special about the xlWorksheet constructor in ExcelIO.cpp, it just reads the COM object and assigns the private variables.

You'll notice there is a template specialization for `getCell()` for strings since COM likes to return `_bstr_t` types, so the specialization is just to strip the `_bstr_t` down to a `std::string`.

If in main.cpp I include ExcelIO.h and construct a xlWorksheet and call `getCell<type>(...);` I get the link error. Why is this when I can call it from within ExcelIO perfectly fine?

I've followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374953/include-comutil-h-cause-errors) which is similar, but haven't had any luck.

For reference, the complete error is (when calling with a double template):

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class _variant_t __thiscall Excel::Range::GetItem(class _variant_t const &,class _variant_t const &)" (?GetItem@Range@Excel@@QAE?AV_variant_t@@ABV3@0@Z) referenced in function "public: double __thiscall xlWorksheet::getCell<double>(int,int)" (??$getCell@N@xlWorksheet@@QAENHH@Z)
```

Comment: It is a strange problem, GetItem() is an inline function provided by the auto-generated .tli file.  But the compiler somehow does not emit it into the .obj file.  The implied conversion from `_variant_t` to T is fishy by itself.  The VS version needs to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

When you #import the dlls/OLB files, it should create a pair of files that automatically are compiled into your project -- a .TLH and a .TLI file.  There should be one pair of these for each import.  The .TLH is the header and the .TLI is the implementation.  A link error would seem to indicate that you are finding the .TLH but for some reason Visual Studio is not compiling the .TLI into your project.

Double check to be sure the files are there, in your project directory and that the function Excel::Range::GetItem() is in both.

Try removing the empty declaration of the specialized version of getCell from the xlWorkSheet class declaration.  That is, remove this bit:

```
template <>
string getCell<string>(int m, int n);
```

...and just leave the specialization below.  Also, either mark the specialization as "inline" or move it to completely inside of the class.

If that does not help, try writing a simple, regular, function (not a template specialization but a function) that does what your specialized version does -- that returns a string.  Try calling *that* from your main.cpp first.  Do you still get the link error.

Finally if *that* does not help -- and assuming the TLH/TLI files are there and the function is in them, then try (for a test only) manually #including the .TLI file in one of your CPP files (or temporarily adding the TLI file to your project) and build again.  You shouldn't *ever* need to do this in practice but if it eliminates the error then at least it reveals the source of the problem.